# Is there any reason to place more expensive Smurf houses?

Tags: smurfs-village

So I can build houses for my Smurfs, which is great. Looks like I have options, too! Some are more expensive, but they seem to just cost more to give me one more Smurf in my village, when the cheapest house gives me that same Smurf.

Is there any reason to build expensive Smurf houses?

Answer (score 1):

If time is a factor, then you'll notice the more expensive ones being quicker to build.  The effect is two-fold, because you free up the building smurf and gain access to the new house quicker (which you could then upgrade for 500g for another smurf after a certain point).